# Oracle 11gR2 - How To Audit SYS.USER$ Table

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, audit, system-tables

I have a Oracle 11gR2 database and I want to audit all select operations on SYS.USER$ table for which users select on this table. When I try this command (I'm trying to run this command with SYS user):

```
audit select on SYS.USER$;
```

It gives error below:

> ERROR at line 1:
>
> ORA-00701: object necessary for warmstarting database cannot be
> altered

How can I audit this table?

Best regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11g this cannot be audited. There are ways of doing it in 12c and up. That said, only users with the "select any dictionary" privilege should be able to select from that table, and anyone with that privilege should be trusted.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.